# TextFormField validation for single textFormField and how to hide the validation after a button is pressed

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and am learning about validations in textFormFields and forms. In my app I have a form with 2 textFormFields and a submit button which should stay disabled if form is not valid. It works as expected but as the autoValidate is set to onUserInteraction, both the textFormFields show their validators even if any one of the textfield is being changed. I have also set `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` for individual textFormFields. Here's the problem:

Initial:

[image]

Problematic:

[image]

There is also another error. When submit button is pressed, the validators don't show null but stay activated like so:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Program9 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Program9({super.key});

  @override
  State<Program9> createState() => _Program9State();
}

class _Program9State extends State<Program9> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final kEmailRegExp = RegExp(r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$');
  bool _isButtonDisabled = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _validateInputs() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _isButtonDisabled = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isButtonDisabled = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Program 9'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _emailController,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('Email', style: kDefaultTextStyle),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your email address';
                  }
                  if (!kEmailRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                    return 'Enter a valid email address';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onChanged: (_) {
                  _validateInputs();
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('Password', style: kDefaultTextStyle),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your password';
                  } else if (value.length < 8) {
                    return 'Password must be atleast 8 characters long';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onChanged: (_) {
                  _validateInputs();
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _isButtonDisabled
                    ? null
                    : () {
                        print(
                          'Email: ${_emailController.text}, Password: ${_passwordController.text}',
                        );
                        _emailController.clear();
                        _passwordController.clear();
                        setState(() {
                          _isButtonDisabled = true;
                        });
                      },
                child: const Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. How to make only a single textField show validation on userInteraction instead of both?
2. How to make the validators stop showing after the button is pressed?